# News Feed Not Arranging by Data in AngularJS

Tags: asp.net, angularjs

Our financial news site tab scrapes Google News for latest related news stories. These should then be displayed from newest to oldest - however they are being arranged by the the day value only, instead of taking into account dd/mm/yyyy

```
                                            <ul class="media-list">
                                            <li ng-repeat="feed in vm.feeds | orderBy: '-Date'" class="media">
                                                <div class="media-body">
                                                    <p>Published: {{feed.Date}}</p>
                                                    <h4 class="media-heading"><a target="_new" href="{{feed.Url}}" ng-bind-html="feed.Title"></a></h4>
                                                </div>
                                                <hr ng-if="!$last" />
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
```

Attached is an image of how this is displaying the news feeds.

Any thoughts on how this can be fixed?[news feed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8TCLU.png)

This is the call in the Controller.JS if it helps

```
 var urlFriendlyName = vm.Detail.Name.split(' ').join('+');
            var newsUrl = 'https://api.quiktech.uk/api/feed?url=https://news.google.com/news/feeds?q=%22' + urlFriendlyName + '%22+stock&output=rss&count=20'
            vm.feeds = [];
            $scope.newsLoading = true;

            getFeeds();
            function getFeeds() {
                $.ajax({
                    url: newsUrl,
                    type: "GET",
                    crossDomain: true,
                    success: function (data) {
                        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                            data[i].Url = $sce.trustAsHtml(data[i].Url);
                            data[i].Title = $sce.trustAsHtml(data[i].Title);
                            vm.feeds.push(data[i]);
                        }
                        $scope.newsLoading = false;
                    }
                });
            }
```

Comment: What does the feed object look like?  What does the value of feed.Date property look like?

Comment: Hi our developer went awol so trying to figure this out myself - have posted what I can find in the controller.js - does that help?

Comment: Not really, is the Date property an actual Date object or just a string?

Comment: I am not sure, is there a quickfire way of finding this out? It is getting scraped from google news - perhaps there is a way to publish it via what is receives from google news as opposed to the feed date

Comment: inside your for loop put console.log(data[i].Date); see what value gets output to the console

Comment: sorry mate will have to break this down into real noobie speak. Where do I locate/add the for loop